# Why are these two series of Bessel functions equal?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I noticed that the following expression holds true for $k \in \left[-1,1\right]$:

$$
\operatorname{J}_{0}\left(x\right) +
2\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{\rm i}^{n}\operatorname{J}_n\left(x\right)\cos\left(n \cos^{-1}\left(k\right)\right) =
\operatorname{J}_{0}\left(kx\right) +
2\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{\rm i}^{n} \operatorname{J}_{n}\left(kx\right),
$$
where $\operatorname{J}_{n}$ is the Bessel function of the first kind and ${\rm i} = \sqrt{-1}$ is the imaginary unit.

It is related to the Jacobi-Anger expansion.
I stumbled upon this equality, it fascinates me, and I don't understand how it is equal.
I have checked numerically for many values of $x$.

Appreciate any advice or explanation $!$.

Comment: Keep in mind that $\cos(n\arccos x)=T_n(x)$ where $T_n$ is the $n$th [Chebyshev polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials). Not sure if this helps.

Comment: Please, see [Bessel Functions: Generating Function and Associated Series](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.12). It can be useful.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a complete answer, as I don't recognize the exact equality. However, I can point out a few things that you could look into.

Both sides are Neumann series of Bessel functions.

$\cos(n\cos^{-1}(k))$ is a Chebyshev polynomial evaluated at $k$.

It looks like one side uses a scaled version of the other. So the multiplication theorem may come into play:
\begin{equation*}
\lambda^{-\nu}J_\nu(\lambda z)
= 
\sum_{n=0}^\infty
\frac{1}{n!} \left(\frac{(1-\lambda)^2z}{2} \right)^n J_{\nu+n}(z)
\end{equation*}

Using the the multiplication theorem on the RHS, you may recognize a series representation of the Chebyshev polynomials appearing.

**Note:** If you find this equality interesting, you should check out Watson's *A Treatise on the Theory of Bessel Functions*